# Isn't it reasonable to not have to post a "perfect" post?

Tags: support

I have been prevented from posting on Electrical Engineering for 5 days.

I along with others post because we are looking for help.

I am not an electrical engineer.

Just an electronic hobbyist.

Before someone rushes to hit their "down vote button", they should consider their motivation.

Am I here to help others or penalize them for making honest mistakes?

I would like to continue posting, but I have other sites that help cheerfully.

Comment: (1) Our [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) provides a decent training ground for writing questions with decent quality.  The customs are more relaxed there.  Which cuts both ways, of course.  (2) "Am I here to help others [...] ?"  You haven't posted any answers, have you?  Whom have you helped?

Comment: @NickAlexeev, posting a question that is useful to others is also helping others. This isn't just a site for people who answer questions.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev Most questions I have seen are way more advanced than my knowledge. When I can help I do.

Comment: is this a question or a rant?

Comment: I'll upvote this.  I don't think your recent closed questions were that bad, and the  comment about answering is simply misguided

Comment: @Scott If he has been forbidden from posting, it likely isn't because of the three downvotes we can see over his two last questions (out of 7, with almost all of them having been upvoted, including the downvoted ones). If such stats somehow can lead to question ban, I'd say there is a problem in the system, indeed. I bet the real cause is somewhere in some deleted posts we can't see.

Comment: This fellow is a help vampire.  Fits the profile quite well.  His Q-ban is well deserved.  And now he came to fish for your pity.

Comment: @Nick Alexeev You have an anger problem.

Comment: @fixit7  I want EE.SE to have high quality content.

Comment: No you don't. Your negative incendiary posts are evidence of that. Until you learn how to treat others, I will NO longer respond to your posts.

Comment: Good riddance.  "Am I here to help others...?"  If we look at your actual activity, the answer is "No, you aren't here to help others".   You haven't helped anyone on this board.  You haven't posted any answers.  You haven't posted any comments which helped anyone, except yourself.  Your questions are slightly below mediocre, and the members (not me or any other moderator) got you a Q-ban.

Answer (score 4):

I sympathize with your point of view.

The people at this site will give you some very good and detailed answers if you put your questions correctly. As a newcomer you have fallen foul of an automated system intended to discourage bad questions.

Do not get discouraged, try to learn from your mistakes. I am sure you have taken the "tour" through the help. There are many good tutorials out there which cover the basics of electronics if you are serious as a hobbyist go through them before asking questions here, but if there is stuff there you don't understand come here and ask detailed and specific questions.

Besides what is in the guidelines for questions there are one or two things that are a hot button at the moment. Particularly the amount of electronic junk that is coming out of certain geographies without proper specifications or documentation. Avoid asking us to fill in for this lack of proper documentation, it will get a negative response.

Comment: This is confusing to me. "Particularly the amount of electronic junk that is coming out of certain geographies without proper specifications or documentation. Avoid asking us to fill in for this lack of proper documentation, it will get a negative response." As far as future posting, I am very leary. I get too many down votes. I am on other stack exchange sites where down votes occasionally occur, but not on a regular basis.

Comment: "This is confusing to me."  What's confusing?  What you didn't get?  EE.SE isn't the volunteer application support for eBay, Amazon, Aliwhatever, and the like.  When you have question about their stuff, post the questions to them.  They are making money by selling the product to you.  They are saving money by not providing technical information (datasheets, manuals, schematics).  Thus, *they* should answer your questions.